# Maximized WS_POPUP window goes in front of the taskbar

Tags: c++, window, gdi, createwindow

I'm creating a window in C++ with that code:

```
HWnd = CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName,
    "myapp",
    WS_POPUP |WS_VISIBLE,
    10, 10, 1000, 800, 0, 0, hInst, NULL);
```

It appears as I want but when I maximize it with like this:

```
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

then it's like a fullscreen window so that the taskbar is hidden.
I think it's because it is a POPUP window but this is like I want it to appear.

Do I need to create my own maximize function or is there a parameter to avoid that ?

Thanks

Comment: Allowing a popup window to be maximized is not appropriate.  Consider stopping the user from maximizing it with GetSystemMenu + EnableMenuItem.  Or handle WM_GETMINMAXINFO to limit the bounds to the monitor's working area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX` style.

If you want your window to be without caption then you will need to adjust window size manually to fit into desktop work area that you can query using [`SystemParametersInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx) specifying `SPI_GETWORKAREA` flag.

Comment: Yes I don't want caption, with SystemParametersInfo It's easy, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature where [the Taskbar will get out of your full-screen application:](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050505-04/?p=35703)

> If you want to create a fullscreen window that covers the taskbar, just create a fullscreen window and the taskbar will automatically get out of the way.
>
> I’ve seen people hunt for the taskbar window and then do a ShowWindow(hwndTaskbar, SW_HIDE) on it. This is nuts for many reasons.
>
> Don’t do any of this messing with the taskbar. Just create your fullscreen window and let the taskbar do its thing automatically.

*Since this is Stackoverflow, a combination of Wikipedia and Reddit, i want this relevant information saved for the next guy asking this question.*